# Why is database_cleaner breaking my tests (minitest / capybara / factory girl)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, factory-bot, minitest

I'm trying to get `database_cleaner` working with my test suite and I can't find anything online about this error:

`ERROR Couldn't find User with id=1`

The tests run fine until I add `database_cleaner`. This is how I'm using it in my `test_helper.rb` file:

```
# Database cleaner.
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
class MiniTest::Spec
  before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

It also does not work if my strategy is `:transaction`.

Comment: Are you using fixtures? Maybe it's an order problem and your fixtures are loaded first. Then DatabaseCleaner.clean removes all previously loaded fixtures. I'm doing the clean-up after the test (in the teardown), and I'm telling DatabaseCleaner to start tracking only in the setup (DatabaseCleaner.start).

Comment: You could try to `puts` a unique line in every `before` block you run (creating the test data, DatabaeCleaner.clean, etc.). Maybe it's an order problem.

Comment: I think it might be an order problem. I can get the tests passing if I put `DatabaseCleaner.clean` at the top of all my tests that use Factory Girl. But if I try and put that line in a before block in my `test_helper.rb` they still fail. It seems brittle to have to call `DatabaseCleaner.clean` at the start of every test though. It also worries me that the fact it doesn't work to call it in a before block in the test_helper.rb might be an indication of a deeper problem with my tests.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#minitest-example), the call to `DatabaseCleaner.clean` should be in an after hook, and `DatabaseCleaner.start` in a before hook (the start call may be unnecessary with the truncation strategy.

What may well be happening here is that database cleaner is clearing out any data you've setup in other before hooks before your actual test runs.  It will depend which order the before hooks run in.